# Agora.io Education_web Project

Tags: reactjs, agora.io

When i am going to run the education-web project in windows it gives errors as[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/thIZV.png)

how to fix this issues...

Comment: always post a minimal reproducible code with your question. It helpf pinpointing the bug if any.

Answer (score 0):

I modified my package.json > scripts > dev
and added

```
"dev": "cross-env TSC_COMPILE_ON_ERROR=false REACT_APP_RUNTIME_PLATFORM=web REACT_APP_AGORA_APP_ID=<secret> REACT_APP_NETLESS_APP_ID=<secret> react-app-rewired start",
```